# Any way to include ServerContext in calls to Handler?

Tags: thrift

I have implemented `TServerEventHandler` on my Java thrift server and there I assign stuff like id to every connection. I'm wondering if there's a way to access context that's passed to `processContext` from handler also to verify for example that the id is correct one.

Is there some easy way to do this?

Comment: AFAIK you can't access the context from the handler. It's not really a context that is supposed to be [consumed by handlers at all](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/2bb6f51dda6838a7d7c946d4a0ee50f40bcda54b/lib/java/src/org/apache/thrift/server/TSimpleServer.java#L78). Can't tell much about the original idea, but I know that for some languages the whole event code is optional and can be entirely excluded from CodeGen. => What ID are you talking about? Can you tell more about that?

Comment: @JensG I have a class that implements `ServerContext` I put my own generated ID attribute there to identify between different clients. (Like [link](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/2bb6f51dda6838a7d7c946d4a0ee50f40bcda54b/lib/java/test/org/apache/thrift/test/TestServer.java#L86) What I'd need to do is to know which client is running the method on handler and keep info on different clients between different calls. I hoped I could achieve it by creating a new ServerContext when client connects, pass it to handler when client calls method and finally delete ServerContext when client is done.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I have the same requirement now.

Answer (score 0):

I put the field in threadLocal, use it with ThriftServiceEventHandler. clientIpThreadLocal.get(). it works, but not beautiful.

```
public class ThriftServiceEventHandler  implements TServerEventHandler {
    public static ThreadLocal<String> clientIpThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal<>();

    /**
     * Called before the server begins.
     */
    @Override
    public void preServe() {

    }

    /**
     * Called when a new client has connected and is about to being processing.
     */
    @Override
    public ServerContext createContext(TProtocol input, TProtocol output) {
        TTransport inputTransport = input.getTransport();
        if (inputTransport instanceof TSocket) {
            TSocket tsocket = (TSocket)inputTransport;
            Socket socket = tsocket.getSocket();
            InetAddress inetAddress = socket.getInetAddress();
            String hostAddress = inetAddress != null ? inetAddress.getHostAddress(): null;
            clientIpThreadLocal.set(hostAddress);
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Called when a client has finished request-handling to delete server context.
     */
    @Override
    public void deleteContext(ServerContext serverContext, TProtocol input, TProtocol output) {
        clientIpThreadLocal.remove();
    }

    /**
     * Called when a client is about to call the processor.
     */
    @Override
    public void processContext(ServerContext serverContext, TTransport inputTransport, TTransport outputTransport) {

    }
}
```